# How do I full text search on a datetime column?

Tags: mysql, index, full-text-search, datetime

I created is a `DATETIME` column. I also tried to change all Collation's of that table to the same utf8 type but it wouldn't stick.  Is it possible to do a FULLTEXT search on a DATETIME column? (%like% is way too slow).

The error I get is:

1283 - Column 'created' cannot be part of FULLTEXT index

--
edit:

```
$add_24 = $i + 1440;

$format_second = date("Y-m-d H:i", strtotime('-'.$add_24.' minutes'));

$p_price = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($con, "SELECT created FROM products WHERE created LIKE '$format_second%'"));
```

Answer (score 3):

`FULLTEXT` only applies to string datatypes, such as `VARCHAR` and `TEXT`.  After all, it is looking for "words".

The charset/collation of a table is only the *default* for *newly added* columns.

You can `ALTER TABLE ... CONVERT TO ...` to change all the columns in a table.  But before doing so, tell us why you are doing it and whether there is already non-English text anywhere in table.  Using that `ALTER` may just make things worse.

What, in particular, are you searching for in the `DATETIME`?  It *may* be possible to change to a 'range' query that *may* run efficiently with an index.  Let's see the attempted query and `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

**More**

```
WHERE created = '2018-01-11 20:49:01'
```

will check for a specific second

or

```
WHERE created >= '2018-01-11'
  AND created  < '2018-01-11' + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

will check for any `created` in a specific day.

Etc.

Either of these examples *may* use an `INDEX` (not `FULLTEXT`) containing `created`.  I say "may" because there could be other issues.  Please provide the `SELECT` and `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

(The API, such as `mysqli`, is not relevant to the question.)

**Still More**

Looking at this formulation...

```
SELECT  symbol,created
    FROM  products
    WHERE  symbol='".$ccc['symbol']."'
      AND  created LIKE '%".$date_format."%'
    ORDER BY  id DESC
    limit  0,48
```

I see that `INDEX(symbol)` is likely to be helpful, but nothing having to do with `created` is useful.  This is because of the *leading* wildcard on the `LIKE`, *and* because an index won't be used with a `DATETIME` and `LIKE`.  The way to get performance via an index is as discussed above (using a range).

Comment: Hey thanks for the response.. I'm trying to efficiently search for a specific date (ex: 2018-01-11 20:49:01) from a DATETIME column but %LIKE% is too slow. The table has about 8,510,000 rows max at all times.

Comment: @MarcAlexander - see my additions.

Comment: $add_24 = $i + 1440;

$format_second = date("Y-m-d H:i", strtotime('-'.$add_24.' minutes'));

$p_price = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($con, "SELECT created FROM products WHERE created LIKE '$format_second%'"));

Comment: I edited the OP.

Comment: @MarcAlexander - For performance of a 1-minute range, see my example and `INDEX` (except change `DAY` to `MINUTE`).  Also, I would do the date arithmetic in SQL, not PHP.

Comment: Do you think it would be more beneficial to just convert DATETIME to a string and then search that way?

Comment: Tried your answer and it still uses 20% of CPU in order to search 1 query..

Comment: 40% on the second try :/

Comment: @MarcAlexander - Plz show us the `SELECT` now.

Comment: $first_price = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($con, "SELECT symbol,created FROM products WHERE symbol='".$ccc['symbol']."' AND created LIKE '%".$date_format."%' ORDER BY id DESC limit 0,48") or die(mysqli_error($con)));

Answer (score 0):

## Don't compare `DATETIME` as a string.

First Rick James, answer is right and should be accepted. You have 3 type categories in MySQL, essentially, [you can see them here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/data-type-overview.html). (Maybe sometime in the future, you'll have a real JSON type.)

- Numeric
- Date/Time
- String

There are types in each of those.  Each of those types has it's own set of operators, and functions. **You should always use that types operators and functions.** Don't think of a `DATETIME`, as a string. Think of it as an object that is stringified by default. For your use case,

- [Date and Time Type Overview](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-type-overview.html)
- **Special Attention**: [Date and Time Functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html)